# What do plus signs on either side of a variable mean?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I once saw a long line of code inside an inline "onclick" and was wondering what the + signs mean on either side of the variables. Are they important? **The example, watered-down code (if I remember correctly) looks something like this:**

```
var HTML = '<a onclick="$('+ variable_id1 +'").show(); ></a>
```

Any information would be great!

Comment: Definitely a duplicate. Sorry guys! I couldnt find that earlier!

Answer (score 2):

The `plus` signs are for string concatenation.

Answer (score 1):

That's a string concatenation. Your code is

```
var HTML = string1 + string2 + string3;
```

with string1 and string3 being string literals and string2 being your variable.

Answer (score 1):

String concatenation, the id is being dynamically retrieved